# Finding balanced disjoint cycles in bridgeless cubic graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory

Petersen's theorem states that a bridgeless cubic graph contains a perfect matching (1-factor). Motivated by this question, [Complexity of finding 2 vertex-disjoint (|V|/2)-cycles in cubic graphs?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/complexity-of-finding-2-vertex-disjoint-v-2-cycles-in-cubic-graphs) I am interested in the problem of deciding the existence of perfect matching $M$ such that removing the edges of $M$ leaves two node-disjoint cycles of equal cardinality  (each cycle has size $|V|/2$).

> Is this problem solvable in P-time? Is it $NP$-complete?

The input is connected bridgeless cubic graph.

Comment: Restricted to bridgeless cubic graphs?

Comment: Yes David. Input is restricted to bridgeless cubic graphs.

Comment: Do you have either a reason for expecting anything but NP-completeness as the answer, or a reason why an NP-completeness proof would actually be interesting?

Comment: @DavidEppstein I expect NP-completeness because of the special structure of $E-M$. Also, I know that Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete on bridgeless cubic graphs.

Comment: Also presumably you mean 2-edge-connected when you say bridgeless. If you take two disjoint copies of a hard instance for Hamiltonian cycle on bridgeless cubic graphs then the result is hard for your problem and has no bridges. But maybe you would consider that a cheat.

Comment: @DavidEppstein  Yes I mean 2-edge-connected graph. Also the input is connected bridgeless cubic graph. So yes, that is a cheat :) What is your guess? Do you think it is NPC and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is NP-complete; reduction from the question, "Does a 2-edge-connected cubic graph $H$ contain a Hamiltonian cycle avoiding a given edge $e$?"

Construct $G$ as follows.  Take two copies of $H-e$, denoting the endpoints of $e$ in the first copy $v_1$, $u_1$ and denoting the endpoints of $e$ in the second copy $v_2$, $u_2$.  Add edges $e_v$ between $v_1$ and $v_2$, and $e_u$ between $u_1$ and $u_2$.  Observe that $G$ is 2-edge-connected.

Any cycle of $G$ contains both or neither of $e_v$ and $e_u$, since these edges form an edge cut.  Thus if $G$ has two vertex-disjoint cycles of length $|V(H)|$, they must each lie in a separate copy of $H$.  Such cycles exist precisely if $H$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle avoiding $e$.

Edit: Am I missing something obvious, or is the question of finding a good perfect matching clearly equivalent to finding the two long cycles?

Comment: Just to clarify, To prove the $NP$-completeness of "Does a 2-edge-connected cubic graph $H$ contain a Hamiltonian cycle avoiding a given edge $e$?", Are you reducing from "Given a cubic graph $G$ and an edge $e$ in $G$, is there a Hamiltonian cycle through $e$"? problem?

Comment: I am reducing from "Does a 2-edge-connected cubic graph $H$ contain a Hamiltonian cycle?"

To solve this, solve the edge-specified problem three times: once for each edge around a vertex.

Comment: So this is a Cook reduction. Right? Also, I guess two times are enough.

Comment: Yes, two times are enough actually.  Note that the reduction preserves planarity and biparteness.